# Using overlay scrollbars with startx?

Tags: lubuntu, overlay-scrollbars

Previously I used slim to replace lxdm ini my Lubuntu, but afterwards my slim error. Now I use startx to enter the desktop and somehow I started to like it, but the problem comes when my overlay scrollbar do not work if I go to the desktop using the startx command.

Can I use overlay scrollbars again when I enter my desktop using startx?

[image: screenshot]